# Ruby on Rails: Cap production deploy not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, web-deployment, capistrano

I finished my app thats running with Ruby on Rails on my local machine. Now I want to finally deploy it fallowing a video from Youtube (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xpYpaRUFzTI&t=888s).
When I type

> cap production deploy

I get following error:

```
#<Thread:0x0000010ea8efd910 C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/sshkit-1.21.2/lib/sshkit/runners/parallel.rb:10 run> terminated with exception (report_on_exception is true):
C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/net-ssh-6.1.0/lib/net/ssh/authentication/ed25519_loader.rb:21:in `raiseUnlessLoaded': OpenSSH keys only supported if ED25519 is available (NotImplementedError)
net-ssh requires the following gems for ed25519 support:
 * ed25519 (>= 1.2, < 2.0)
 * bcrypt_pbkdf (>= 1.0, < 2.0)
See https://github.com/net-ssh/net-ssh/issues/565 for more information
LoadError : "cannot load such file -- bcrypt_pbkdf_ext"
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/net-ssh-6.1.0/lib/net/ssh/key_factory.rb:200:in `classify_key'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/net-ssh-6.1.0/lib/net/ssh/key_factory.rb:51:in `load_data_private_key'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/net-ssh-6.1.0/lib/net/ssh/key_factory.rb:42:in `load_private_key'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/net-ssh-6.1.0/lib/net/ssh/authentication/key_manager.rb:167:in `sign'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/net-ssh-6.1.0/lib/net/ssh/authentication/methods/publickey.rb:62:in `authenticate_with'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/net-ssh-6.1.0/lib/net/ssh/authentication/methods/publickey.rb:20:in `block in authenticate'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/net-ssh-6.1.0/lib/net/ssh/authentication/key_manager.rb:132:in `block in each_identity'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/net-ssh-6.1.0/lib/net/ssh/authentication/key_manager.rb:129:in `each'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/net-ssh-6.1.0/lib/net/ssh/authentication/key_manager.rb:129:in `each_identity'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/net-ssh-6.1.0/lib/net/ssh/authentication/methods/publickey.rb:19:in `authenticate'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/net-ssh-6.1.0/lib/net/ssh/authentication/session.rb:86:in `block in authenticate'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/net-ssh-6.1.0/lib/net/ssh/authentication/session.rb:72:in `each'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/net-ssh-6.1.0/lib/net/ssh/authentication/session.rb:72:in `authenticate'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/net-ssh-6.1.0/lib/net/ssh.rb:255:in `start'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/sshkit-1.21.2/lib/sshkit/backends/connection_pool.rb:63:in `call'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/sshkit-1.21.2/lib/sshkit/backends/connection_pool.rb:63:in `with'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/sshkit-1.21.2/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:177:in `with_ssh'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/sshkit-1.21.2/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:130:in `execute_command'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/sshkit-1.21.2/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:148:in `block in create_command_and_execute'
        from <internal:kernel>:90:in `tap'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/sshkit-1.21.2/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:148:in `create_command_and_execute'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/sshkit-1.21.2/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:61:in `test'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/capistrano-rbenv-2.2.0/lib/capistrano/tasks/rbenv.rake:10:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/sshkit-1.21.2/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:31:in `instance_exec'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/sshkit-1.21.2/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:31:in `run'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/sshkit-1.21.2/lib/sshkit/runners/parallel.rb:12:in `block (2 levels) in execute'
(Backtrace restricted to imported tasks)
cap aborted!
NotImplementedError: OpenSSH keys only supported if ED25519 is available
net-ssh requires the following gems for ed25519 support:
 * ed25519 (>= 1.2, < 2.0)
 * bcrypt_pbkdf (>= 1.0, < 2.0)
See https://github.com/net-ssh/net-ssh/issues/565 for more information
LoadError : "cannot load such file -- bcrypt_pbkdf_ext"

Tasks: TOP => rbenv:validate
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

My Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }

ruby '3.0.3'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails', branch: 'main'
gem 'rails', '~> 6.1.4', '>= 6.1.4.1'
gem 'pg'
# Use Puma as the app server
gem 'puma', '~> 5.0'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '>= 6'
# Transpile app-like JavaScript. Read more: https://github.com/rails/webpacker
gem 'webpacker', '~> 5.0'
# Turbolinks makes navigating your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.7'
gem 'rbnacl', '< 5.0', :require => false                                                                                                                                                                
#gem 'rbnacl-libsodium', :require => false                                                                                                                                                               
gem 'bcrypt_pbkdf', '< 2.0', :require => false
# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
# gem 'redis', '~> 4.0'
# Use Active Model has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'
gem 'ed25519', '>= 1.2', '< 2.0'

# Use Active Storage variant
#gem 'image_processing', '~> 1.2'
#gem 'activestorage-validations'

# Reduces boot times through caching; required in config/boot.rb
gem 'bootsnap', '>= 1.4.4', require: false

#devise
gem 'devise', '~> 4.8'

#activeadmin
gem 'activeadmin', '~> 2.9'

#ransack
gem 'ransack', '~> 2.5'

#pagination
gem 'kaminari', '~> 1.2', '>= 1.2.2'

gem 'capistrano', '~> 3.11'
gem 'capistrano-passenger', '~> 0.2.0'
gem 'capistrano-rails', '~> 1.4'
gem 'capistrano-rbenv', '~> 2.1', '>= 2.1.4'

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
end

group :development do
  # Access an interactive console on exception pages or by calling 'console' anywhere in the code.
  gem 'web-console', '>= 4.1.0'
  # Display performance information such as SQL time and flame graphs for each request in your browser.
  # Can be configured to work on production as well see: https://github.com/MiniProfiler/rack-mini-profiler/blob/master/README.md
  gem 'rack-mini-profiler', '~> 2.0'
  # Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
  gem 'sqlite3', '~> 1.4'
end

group :test do
  # Adds support for Capybara system testing and selenium driver
  gem 'capybara', '>= 3.26'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
  # Easy installation and use of web drivers to run system tests with browsers
  gem 'webdrivers'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

It shows me in the error message, that I showld add both of those gems. But then I still get the same error message. Does somebody know how I can solve that probleme? That would realy help me a lot. Thank you so much for your time reading this. I hope I described my problem as precise as possible.

Comment: I don't know where `bcrypt_pbkdf` is coming from as you'd normally just include the `bcrypt` gem but neither should have an impact on deployment other than failing to start the server if gems are not available. Did you bundle install after adding the gems? you should only need

Answer (score -1):

If you are using mac, then run the following command. It will fix this issue.

```
ssh-add
```